# Where to put this code of javascript to work properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have three files separated.

1."index.php"

```
<div id="content">
    <?php include_once("template_main_aside.php"); ?>
</div>

<?php include_once("template_footer.php"); ?>
```

2."template_main_aside.php"

```
<aside id="main_aside">
    <ul id="menu1">
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu6</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

3."style.css"

```
#content {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:1000px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #999;
}
#content > #main_aside {
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 19%;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 7px #999;
}
#content > #main_aside > ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#content > #main_aside > ul:first-child > li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#content > #main_aside > ul:first-child > li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;    
}
#content > #main_aside > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 7px 7px 10px;
}
#content > #main_aside > ul > li > a:hover {
    background: #fdb945;
    color: #fff;
}
.selected a {
    background: #fdb945;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Lastly,

I am trying to use following javascript code to lock the style of selected menu navigation in orange background:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#menu1 li').click(function() {
            $('#menu1 li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            //$('a', this).addClass('selected');
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works when I do this in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uakuxjy0/1/):

But when I'm working on my local files, I am not sure where I should put the javascript.
I've tried in body section of "index.php", at the end of "template_main_aside.php" but neither works.

Help please!

Comment: Do you have jQuery available to you in the page? Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: Put it into a JS file. Then make script tag to load jquery and after that one for your own JS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it just above the closing `body` tag but be sure to put a reference to jQuery before that i.e.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#menu1 li').click(function() {
                    $('#menu1 li').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    //$('a', this).addClass('selected');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit:

The src link is to **jQuery**, which is the framework you are using! (all those `$` signs). It is always important that jquery is referenced in a page before you begin using it. In the example I have loaded it from the Google CDN, in practise it may be that you have a version of it on your own server or locally. In that case you would just link to it *relatively* - for example if its in your `js` folder called `jquery` it would be: `/js/jquery.js`.

Comment: This works! Thanks @Djave btw what is that src link? Should I always add it whenever I use javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it into the `<head>` tag.

```
<head>
<script>
your js code here
</script>
</head>
```

You can also reference the js file

```
<script src="yourJSfile.js"></script>
```

If your code also contains jquery you have to add the jquery script ass well. You can download it here: http://jquery.com/download/

Then add it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add javascript code to php files but css.

try this

add javascript to

"template_main_aside.php" file.

like

```
`<script>
your js code here
</script>
<aside id="main_aside">
<ul id="menu1">
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu6</a></li>
</ul>
</aside>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can put JavaScript anywhere in the html or PHP file. Loading JavaScript in footer is popular trend in web development. Since it increase some speed of page. First HTML  code is loaded  and then JavaScript start to do its work. So in index.php

```
 <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="content">
      <?php include_once("template_main_aside.php"); ?>
      </div>    
      <?php include_once("template_footer.php"); ?>
     <!--jquery (load jquery.min.js before any coding on jquery )-->
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#menu1 li').click(function() {
                $('#menu1 li').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                //$('a', this).addClass('selected');
            });
        });
    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

or make separate file for JavaScript code. In this way code is more manageable.
in your index.php

```
        <html>
          <head>
          </head>
          <body>
          <div id="content">
          <?php include_once("template_main_aside.php"); ?>
          </div>    
          <?php include_once("template_footer.php"); ?>
         <!--jquery (load jquery.min.js before any coding on jquery )-->
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="url/to/main.js">

          </body>
    </html>
```

and in your main.js

```
$(function() {
                $('#menu1 li').click(function() {
                    $('#menu1 li').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');

                });
            });
```